# Plot text is "blurry" on X11 device

Tags: r, graph, x11, blurry

I'm having the problem that since the upgrade on Mac to OS X Yosemite, my graphs in R are blurry. Specifically, the text and the axis I additionally added to a graph are blurry. Also I cannot access the history of graphs.

Do you know what might be the reason?

[image: Test Graph Here]
<sub>(source: [bplaced.net](http://www.unisg.bplaced.net/test_graph.png))</sub>

With this code:

```
X11()
boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, col = "lightgray", main="plot title")
```

the title "plot title" and the axis are still blurry.

Comment: Could you post a minimal complete code example that produces blurry output on your computer? The less code the better.

Comment: `X11() ; boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, col = "lightgray", main="plot title")` on my Yosemite Mac (R 3.1.1) produces similar results, @NPE

Comment: Hi xrbrmstr and NPE, also with your code it does not work well. The axis and the title are still blurry.

Comment: Just tried the same on a Mountain Lion Mac and the plot text is still blurry. Is there a reason you can't use the default Quartz device on your Mac for these plots?

Comment: hrbrmstr, this solved my problem. quartz just did not start normally, i manually fixed the problem. thanks a lot!